# magento sporadic db connection

Tags: php, magento-1.8

So, I was getting the

> "dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract"

error when I moved my install to a staging environment... and could not figure out what the problem was.

So, I checked the `$connConfig` object in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php`

What I discovered is that the object is created 119 times (?!) in the home page creation, and that 81 times it is false and 38 times it is the correct object.

Is this typical? Are there many times where the connection is set without db credentials for some reason? Or... is this my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, there are many times when the db connection object is called with no data and it returns bool(false)... it's just fine.

...for those of you coming here trying to figure out:

> dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

My issue was a module (FishPig::Wordpress) which called a missing external database. The block which was being created was obvious in the debug trace. I just had to disable the createBlock-> call in a template file, or, eventually, install the external db :P